# Ресурсы по искусственному интеллекту для игр

Tags: разработка-игр, книги, искусственный-интеллект

Что можно почитать, человеку, начинающему работать над искусственным интеллектом? Интересует система принятия решений, в частности, персонажи в играх.

Если не трудно, то ссылки на онлайн-книги.

Comment: [Искусственный интеллект](http://pmg.org.ru/ai/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень хорошая книга (ссылки нет, но в сети она была):

> Mat Buckland. Programming Game AI by Example

Ничего лучше не читал (хотя много еще книг просматривал). Сразу же после прочтения написал игрушку с вменяемым ИИ. Если интересует ИИ в некотором отрыве от игр, можете посмотреть книжку

> И.Братко. Алгоритмы искусственного интеллекта на языке PROLOG

Она весьма занимательная с позиции теории, хотя с точки зрения практической полезности - не очень. Но хорошо дополнит первую книгу.

Comment: Ну да,пролог мне не очень понравился. Мне функциональное программирование ближе логического.

Comment: Тоже фп больше люблю. Но в приведенной книге просто много идей по ИИ.

Comment: для любителей фп есть оч приятная книга<br> 
Peter Norvig. Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming<br>
если хорошенько порыться, в сети ее можно найти. но конкретно про игры там ничего нет, и (имхо) книге Братко она проигрывает

Answer (score 0):

Алёна С++ об искусственном интеллекте в играх
http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2010/12/add-2010.html